# Searching Algorithm using listbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox, searchbar, search-box

I am trying to make a search box/ bar by using access Database. i want the code to search for the record and then then remove/hide the record from listbox when i search for another record. My programs belows searches for the Record and displays it, however there are few problems.

1. does not remove/ hide the record when searching again.
2. does not respond if the record isn't in database or if search box is empty.

---

```
 Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\MS Office\project.mdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE productID LIKE '" & txtSearch_Bar.Text & "'", con)
    con.Open()
    Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While (sdr.Read())

        lstbSearchResult.Items.Add(sdr("ProductID"))

    End While
```

i would also like to make this into a dynamic search bar.

Comment: 1, Clear the list before adding new items   2. It surely does "respond" there is just nothing to display.  You can check that 3. You should be disposing of some of those things - read up on the `Using` statement  4. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: The app may also be able to be more economical and faster using a DataSource that you simply filter on.  Also study up on SQL parameters

Comment: How do i remove the data in listbox? - @Plutonix

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].  Clearing and removing items is very easily researched.

Comment: What do you mean by Dynamic search bar?

Comment: drop down view of related data. e.g. if user searches something that begins with "s", the program should display all the data that begins with "s" - @Mary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first requirement is addressed in the comments. For your second requirement, add the following before your While loop.

```
If Not sdr.HasRows Then
    MessageBox.Show("No Matches")
    Exit Sub
End If
```